# Errors when installing magento theme

Tags: magento-1.9

I installed theme from themeforest in Magento 1.9.2

I uploaded

1. Themes files
2. Porto Theme (patch for Configurable Swatches)
3. Porto Theme (patch for Magento 1.9.2.x)

When I complete these 3 steps I get

> showing error ===>
>   Fatal error: Class 'Smartwave_Megamenu_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\durja\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234

in frontend and backend.

Please help me.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: SInce you bought this on themeforest, you can ask the official support from the theme developer about this error. Also don't give out your skype details here, this is not a customer support site...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot to disable compiling and cache before theme installation.

How to disable the compilation:
Open the '/includes/config.php' and comment out 'define' lines (about lines 28-29).

How to clear cache:
You need delete '/var/cache/' directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete cache by: `sudo rm -rf magento/var/cache/*` and refresh your browser.